# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: exception, session, response, state, cgi-bin

I've got this really strange request for an invalid URL on:

```
Invalid URL: /cgi-bin/1st.cgi
```

This is causing the following error:

```
 SEVERE: Exception initializing page context
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2381)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2098)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:833)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:216)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest.getSession(ApplicationHttpRequest.java:544)
...
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is the response stream has been closed.  Either you already sent a redirect, or committed some other type of response.  I recommend getting your session object before you perform any response, and save the response until there is nothing left to do with the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` objects.

A good practice is to return from your Servlet right away after performing a redirect, that way you can avoid some of these problems.

Comment: "A good practice is to return from your Servlet right away after performing a redirect, that way you can avoid some of these problems" good point, among the others, that did the trick for me.

Comment: Can someone give us an example of code please, because I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem because of multiple tag `<h:outputScript target="head">`