# Session Checking with Filter and Redirecting

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

I am trying to do login operation but when I am using filter for checking whether session is valid or not then I got the exception as :-  `java.lang.IllegalStateException`, Cannot create a session after the response has been committed .

Myservlet filter code is :-

```
 public class SessionFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter 
    {

private ArrayList<String> urlList;

     public void destroy() {

}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    throws IOException, ServletException {

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    String url = request.getServletPath();
    boolean allowedRequest = false;


    if(urlList.contains(url)) {
        allowedRequest = true;

    }

    if (!allowedRequest) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (null == session) {
            response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
        }
    }

  chain.doFilter(req, res);



}


public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {

    String urls = fConfig.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");

    //StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");

    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls);

    urlList = new ArrayList<String>();

    urlList.add(token.nextToken());

    /*while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        urlList.add(token.nextToken());

    }*/
}

}



  Filter mapping in web.xml is :-

<filter>
   <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>Filter.SessionFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
      <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
      <param-value>Login.jsp,</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>

    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>

</filter-mapping>
```

Now when I requests for `login.jsp` then i got the this exception . Please help i am 
  getting stuck  on my project since last 2 days here.

Comment: have u try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393160/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has

Comment: if (null == session) what is this?

Comment: After `if (null == session) {
            response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); return; }`. Can you give a try by adding `return` statement after `response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");`

Comment: yes i have tried this but i did not got the point

Comment: But when i use return statement after response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp"); then i did not get any output (i want to redirect to login.jsp) endless processing go on what should i do .Viksh V

Comment: In which line does the Exception occur?

Comment: Do you have any other filter that may be running before this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not continue with filter after doing `sendRedirect`. `sendRedirect` will commit the headers to the client and after that you are not supposed to write anything.

And have the login.jsp to your allowed url's.

```
  if (!allowedRequest) {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    if (null == session || ) {
        response.sendRedirect("Login.jsp");
        return;
    }
}
```

**References:**

[Cause of Servlet's 'Response Already Committed'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305563/cause-of-servlets-response-already-committed)

Comment: This solution was provided to OP in my comments. But, OP says it doesn't work.