# redirect page to login page on session time out in spring mvc without using spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

Its easy to do with Spring Security. But what if I am not using Spring Security and want to redirect the user to login page with a message "Session Expired" in Spring MVC.

Does Spring has any specific method to do this?

Comment: Determine if your user is not logged in and send a redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved.

I added Filters in web.xml.

```
 <filter>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.java.util.SessionFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>avoid-urls</param-name>
        <param-value>/firstPage.htm</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Then created a Filter class

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.StringTokenizer;
    import javax.servlet.Filter;
    import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
    import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    public class SessionFilter implements Filter {

private ArrayList<String> urlList;

public void destroy() {
}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res,
        FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    String url = request.getServletPath();
    boolean allowedRequest = false;
    if (urlList.contains(url)) {
        allowedRequest = true;
    }

    if (!allowedRequest) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (null == session) {
            response.sendRedirect("startup.jsp");
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String urls = config.getInitParameter("avoid-urls");
    StringTokenizer token = new StringTokenizer(urls, ",");
    urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (token.hasMoreTokens()) {
        urlList.add(token.nextToken());

    }
}
}
```

Notice I executed this line " chain.doFilter(request, response);" only when session is active. Otherwise it would give the exception "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do using the following snippet. Try to include this lines in header of the page. And replace the User attribute according to the user session object.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession("User");
if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
   //do something here
} else {
    response.sendRedirect("/redirect_the_page.jsp");
}
```

Comment: I am getting this when its going to response.sendRedirect-> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed. Please suggest

Comment: Refer this : - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4393160/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-response-has

Comment: @SireeshYarlagadda wouldnt the first line cause null pointer exception  if session has timed out and session is null